# Does UV water purification cause cancer?

Tags: photochemistry, purification, water-treatment

I found out that a relative is using a machine that performs UV water purification at home (for drinking).

There seems to be a distinct difference from the water that is not purified by it.

Is it possible that this use of UV radiation may lead to cancer in humans?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: I believe that UV air purifiers make some ozone which might be linked to cancer.  Water seems different because by the time you drink it I don't think that it would have radicals.  UV is used to sanitize medical equipment and sunlight is putting uv into water all the time.

Comment: Thank you joseph-hirsch for your answer. geafix, In general, UV rays are known to cause skin cancer, so that's why I was confused.

Comment: That's right, but it's **not** like your water now contains "dissolved" UV rays or something. They are gone.

Comment: I'm glad I got the answer to this question. But I'm surprised as to why it is off topic and "personal". I only found out about this due to a relative using it. But I sure believe this applies to the entire human kind (or for that matter all living creatures). So I would like this to remain for the benefit of humans. After all, the tag 'water-treatment' is 100% relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that this use of UV radiation may lead to cancer in humans?

No!

The lamps used for water treatment are usually *low pressure mercury vapour lamps*. These lamps emit in the UV-C range with a maximum at $\lambda = 254~\mathrm{nm}$.

- No mercury can escape from an intact lamp.
- In principle, UV-C radiation may cause severe sun burns and harm your eyes. However, the lamps are housed and **the consumer is protected from the direct exposure to radiation**.
- There is no change to the water due to UV irradiation.
- UV-C radiation is efficient in killing microorganisms in water.

Comment: Obviously, the UV is not doing harm to the water and the person who drinks it. Just make sure, that no person gets in contact with the hard UV radiation. Still, when contaminations are present in the water, the UV might alter them to make them even more toxic. For example Br- ions might react to Bromate BrO3- which would indeed be related to cancer. I think in California, some drinking water reservoirs were covered with shade balls, to make sure no UV radiation reaches the water, to eliminate the risk of toxic products being formed.